# Laravel models to return null relation?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am writing a website for photo posts and I have these functions relating likes (they determine if the user is liking the specific post or not)

Post Model:

```
public function likes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Like');
}

public function isLiked()
{
    return $this->likes()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
}
```

Post Controller function for example:

```
public function postsByType($type)
{
    if($this->user){
        $posts = Post::with('isLiked')->where('type', '=', $type)->paginate(12);
    } else {
        $posts = Post::where('type', '=', $type)->paginate(12);
    }
    return $posts;
}
```

Is there any way to return **null** in MODEL function when user is not logged in, **without running a query**?

**I want to avoid writing that *if* in post controller**

I thought about the following solution but it's not working...

```
public function isFollowing()
{
    return $this->setRelation('isFollowing', null);

}
```

getting this error:
        `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query        \Builder::addEagerConstraints()`

Comment: By *when user is not connected* do you mean if the user isn't logged in?

Comment: Exactly, meaning when Auth::user()->id isn't set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you probably always want to fetch the relation (except if there's no user logged in) I suggest you do something like this in your model:
(I also renamed the relationship to `liked`, you'll see later why)

```
public function newQuery(){
    $query = parent::newQuery();
    if(Auth::check()){
        $query->with('liked');
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Now every time a query is run with the model `with('isLiked')` will be added if the user is logged in.

One problem remains though. If you access `isLiked` the query will be run anyways. And even for every post because it's not eager loaded. You can fix that by adding an attribute accessor:

```
public function getIsLikedAttribute(){
    if(Auth::guest) return false;
    return ! $this->liked->isEmpty();
}
```

So in your view you can just do this:

```
@if($post->isLiked)
```

---

Note: It would be nicer to move the things inside `newQuery()` to a global scope. Make sure to check out how to do that in [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#global-scopes) if you're interested.

Here's an example with a scope. Create a class, let's call it `LikedScope`:

```
class LikedScope implements Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ScopeInterface {
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model){
        if(Auth::check()){
            $builder->with('liked');
        }
    }

    public function remove(Builder $builder, Model $model){

    }
}
```

And then add it to your model:

```
public static function boot(){
    parent::boot();
    static::addGlobalScope(new LikedScope);
}
```

Comment: I read the documentation, I don't understand where do I write the trait? how do I use it? could you please write an example ? :(

Comment: You don't need a trait. That's just to make the scope more reusable. See my updated answer for an example.

Comment: ran into troubles, fixed it with this: public function getLikedAttribute(){
        if(Auth::guest()) return false;
        return (bool)count($this->relations['liked']);
    } is that ok?

Comment: You shouldn't name the relation and the attribute accessor the same. That's why I used isLiked and liked

Comment: gotcha :) it's working like a charm, and I understood everything thanks alot!